# Question about my solution on a polynomial equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, polynomials, cubics

I encountered the following problem.

> Let $$P(x) = 2x^3 − 2ax^2 + (a^2 − 81)x − b$$ For $a, b \in \mathbb{N}$, $P(x) = 0$ has $3$ positive integer roots. The value of $a$ is unique, but it yields two distinct values for $b$. Find both values of $b$.

What I did was first apply Vieta's formulas to obtain

$$\begin{align*} a &= p + q + r \\ \frac{a^2-81}{2} &= pq + pr + qr \\ \frac{b}{2} &= pqr \end{align*}$$ where $p,q,r$ are the roots.

The second equation yields $$a^2 = 2(pq + pr + qr) + 81 \quad (1)$$ and squaring the first produces $$a^2 = p^2+q^2+r^2+2(pq + pr + qr) \quad (2)$$

Equating $(1)$ and $(2)$, we know that $$p^2+q^2+r^2=81$$

Because $p,q,r$ are positive integers, we can calculate them by brute force. What I got was, without loss of generality, $$p=1, q=4, r=8$$$$p=3,q=6,r=6$$$$p=4,q=4,r=7$$

Using the last equation from the original set of Vieta's formulas produces $b=64,216,$ or $224$. However, the answer is supposedly only $216,224$. Why is $64$ not a solution? Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you have done everything correctly but, it is given that value of $a$ is unique. So if you take all cases into account, value of a won't be unique.
$Case \ 1: a=13$
$Case \ 2:a =15$
$Case\ 3:a=15$ 
So to get $2$ values of b you should choose $a=15$. Therefore consider only the last 2 solutions.